Extremal combinatorics with $2k+1$ 7-element subsets of a set $ \{1,2,3,...,19,20\}$
Let $A_1,A_2,...A_{2k+1}$ be $7$-element subsets of the set $M = \{1,2,3,\dots,19,20\}$, such that each set  $A_i$ has nonempty intersection with $k$ other sets among these $2k+1$ sets. What is the largest value of $k$ for which it is possible to find such $A_1,\dots,A_{2k+1}$?


If we make a graph $G$ with $A_i$ as a vertices and say $A_i$ is connected to $A_j$ iff their intersection is not empty then we have ${k(2k+1)\over 2}$ edges so $k$ must be even.

Complement graph $\overline{G}$ has no triangles, i.e. among any three sets two must have nonempty intersection.

Graph $G$ contains $k$-clique.
Prove: Let $A:=A_{k+1}$ and if $A$ is not connected with $A_1,A_2,...A_k$ then every $2$ of them are connected since among any three $A,A_i,A_j$ and $i,j\leq k$ two must have nonempty intersection.



Please [edit] your post to avoid non-standard terminology like 'cuts'.  Please improve the title.  Please proof-read the post to correct spelling mistakes.  What is the context in which you encountered this question?  Can you credit the original source?

What is the largest $k$ for which you know of a solution?

Let $G$ be the complement graph to your graph. Then as you have already noted $G$ has $2k+1$ vertices and the following properties: 1) $G$ has no triangles, 2) $G$ is a regular graph of degree $k$. However, such a graph exists only for $k=2$. If I understood you correctly.

@nonuser
No. $k$-clique has graph $\overline{G}$, the graph $G$ has independent $k$-sets.
This fact follows from (1) and (2). Thus the answer to your question is $k=2$. Again, if I understood your question correctly.

I will refine the definitions a bit by slightly changing the notations from my comments.
So, let $G$ be the graph defined by the author of the question,
and let $H=\overline{G}$ be the complement graph to $G$.
Then $H$ has the following properties: (1) $H$ has $2k+1$ vertices, (2) $H$ has no triangles, (3) $H$ is a regular graph of degree $k$.
Lemma.
If $k>2$, then there are no graphs with properties (1),(2), and (3).
Proof.
Let $k>2$ and $H$ be a graph with properties (1),(2), and (3).
Let $A_1$ and $A_2$ be adjacent vertices of $H$.
Since $H$ has no triangles, vertices $A_1$ and $A_2$ have no common neighbours.
Let $A_3,\ldots, A_{k+1}$ and $A_{k+2},\ldots, A_{2k}$ be the remaining neighbours of $A_1$ and $A_2$, respectively (see figure).

We denote by $F$ the subgraph induced by vertices $A_3,\ldots,A_{2k}$ and by $e(F)$ the number of its edges. We have
$$
e(F)+1+2(k-1)+k=\frac{k(2k+1)}{2},
$$
where the last summand in the left-hand side is the number of edges leaving the vertex $A_{2k+1}$ (the degree of vertex $A_{2k+1}$).
It follows that
$$
e(F)=\frac{2k^2-5k+2}{2}.
$$
On the other hand,
$F$ is obtained from a bipartite graph $K_{k-1,k-1}$ with parts $A_3,\ldots, A_{k+1}$ and $A_{k+2},\ldots, A_{2k}$ (these parts are independent sets in $F$) by discarding at least $k-1$ edges.
Indeed, if the neighbours of $A_{2k+1}$ are $A_3,\ldots,A_{k+2}$, then it is necessary to remove edges $A_iA_{k+2}$, $i=3,\ldots,k+1$, total $k-1$ edges;
if the neighbours of $A_{2k+1}$ are $A_4,\ldots,A_{k+2},A_{k+3}$
it is necessary to remove edges $A_iA_{k+2},A_iA_{k+3}$, $i=4,\ldots,k+1$, total $2(k-2)\geq k-1$ edges;
and so on.
It follows that
$$
e(F)\leq (k-1)^2-k-1=(k-1)(k-2).
$$
Hence
$$
\frac{2k^2-5k+2}{2}\leq(k-1)(k-2) 
$$
or $k\leq2$. Contradiction.
It follows from the lemma that the answer to the question posed is $k=2$.
However, it is still necessary to construct $A_1,\ldots,A_5$ for the case $k=2$, but it is easy.
